# Apache returning incorrect bootstrap.min.css file

Tags: apache

Running Apache 2.2 on CentOS 7

I have a `bootstrap.min.css` file:

```
/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

It is version `2.2.1`. However, when I go to `http://example.com/css/bootstrap.min.css`, I get a bootstrap file with version `3.1.1`.

I've verified:

- The file in the /css/ directory in the filesystem is 2.2.1 as expected
- This is not a browser caching issue.
- All other files in that folder work correctly...the bootstrap.css returns the correct file.  It's only the bootstrap.min.css that doesn't work.

In short, apache is simply returning the wrong file, and I've never seen anything like this before.  We've had 3 sets of eyes on this to confirm the problem.

We do have a single rewrite rule on the server:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^_router\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /_router.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

However, this would result in a routing error if it were being used. So, it is not a rewrite issue.

Comment: Try putting another file in the CSS folder and testing whether or not that works, that will help narrow down the problem.

Comment: @TimFountain, we have lots of other files, they all work...but we found the problem, it was an apache .conf file...posting answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution:** remove the `/etc/httpd/conf.d/welcome.conf`

The Apache `welcome.conf` file has some Alias values that affect the website and cause it to return files from the `/usr/share/httpd/` directory instead of the site directory:

```
Alias /.noindex.html /usr/share/httpd/noindex/index.html
Alias /css/bootstrap.min.css /usr/share/httpd/noindex/css/bootstrap.min.css
Alias /css/open-sans.css /usr/share/httpd/noindex/css/open-sans.css
Alias /images/apache_pb.gif /usr/share/httpd/noindex/images/apache_pb.gif
Alias /images/poweredby.png /usr/share/httpd/noindex/images/poweredby.png
```

It was just pure coincidence that we happened to even have a bootstrap file with version 3.1.1 in our directories...and it explains why they were slightly different.

In any case, this means that anyone who uses the path `/css/bootstrap.min.css` on their website (very common setup) may have similar problems where the version they are expecting and the version the browser is getting are different.